# Speeding the computation of Landau's function

Tags: performance-tuning, combinatorics

This computational question is based on [this question of combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2304763/longest-cycle-of-permutation-of-n-elements) on the Mathematics.SE.

A *permutation* of a list of $n$ items, $\{ 1, 2, \ldots, n \}$, is of course a reordering of them.  If one applies the same permutation again and again, one must ultimately return to the original list.  For instance if you have 15 items and permute merely $1 \to 2, 2 \to 1$ (often written as the cycle $(12)$) then the number of permutations (the length of the cycle) is $2$.  If instead you have the permutation $1 \to 2, 2 \to 3, 3 \to 1$ or (123), then you need three such steps.  Permutations can be written as factored into cycles, for instance for 9 items:  $(1345)(26)(78)(9)$, where the lone item $(9)$ is never changed.  (Conventional notation omits such lone items.)

The *maximum* number of steps needed to return to the original ordering over all possible permutations is described by the [Landau function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function) of the number of elements $n$.  The Landau function is the largest least common multiple (LCM) of any `IntegerPartition` of $n$:

```
Landau[n_] := Max[LCM @@@ IntegerPartitions[n]]
```

(It is sequence [A000793 in the OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000793).)

Unfortunately, my simple code is extremely slow, and limits its use to $n<70$ or so depending upon computational resources and time:

```
Timing[Landau[70]]
```

(*

{33.4142, 6126120}

*)

Is there a significantly faster algorithm for computing this function in *Mathematica* that would allow it to be used for much larger $n$?

---

I urge Wolfram Research to add Landau's function to the function calls in *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://oeis.org/A000793 already provides faster *Mathematica* code for this sequence:

```
b[n_, i_] := 
  b[n, i] = Module[{p}, p = If[i < 1, 1, Prime[i]]; 
    If[n == 0 || i < 1, 1, 
     Max[b[n, i - 1], Table[p^j*b[n - p^j, i - 1], {j, Log[p, n]}]]]];

a[n_] := b[n, If[n < 8, 3, PrimePi @ ⌈1.328 * Sqrt[⌊n*Log[n]⌋]⌉ ] ];

a[500]
```

> ```
> 715657920159093382270800
> ```

Credited to [Jean-François Alcover](https://oeis.org/wiki/User:Jean-Fran%C3%A7ois_Alcover), and [Alois P. Heinz](https://oeis.org/wiki/User:Alois_P._Heinz), with mild reformatting of my own.

Comment: Ah... just a matter of finding faster existing code.  Thanks so much.  Accept.